# Optimal Block Size for a hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a four node multi cluster in hadoop. I have run a series of experiments with the block sizes as follows and calculated run time as follows.

All of them are performed on 20GB input file.
64MB  - 32 min, 
128MB - 19 Min, 
256MB - 15 min, 
1GB   - 12.5 min.

Should I proceed further in going for 2GB block size? Also kindly explain an optimal block size if similar operations are performed on 90GB file. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashrith: I need different answers here. Kindly go through the question again before marking them as duplicate.

Comment: The question is very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134288/block-size-in-hadoop you could have modified the original question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Yeah. But, I hardly get answers to my questions after edits.  That is something which happens in stack overflow! A question is active only when it is asked. Due to this experience of mine, I have posted another.

Answer (score 0):

You should test with 2Gb and compare results.

Only you consider the next: More biggest block size minimize the overhead of create maps tasks, but for non-local tasks, Hadoop need transfer all the block to the remote node (network bandwidth limit here), then more smallest block size perform better here.

In your case, 4 nodes (I assume connected by a switch or router local in a LAN), 2Gb isn't a problem. But the answer isn't true in others enviroments, which more error rate.

Comment: thanks. Is it better to use a switch or LAN for doing hadoop operations?

Comment: @re3el The most important factor is the bandwidth of the dispositive. Bandwith, with Disk IO and RAM, are the commonly bounds limit in a Hadoop Cluster. A Switch dedicated only to the Cluster is desirable, but you can use a general switch in your organization if you want.